# How to copy the same local folder structure to docker containers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been trying to copy a python project to the docker container but when I go inside the container and see, the same folder structure does not exist.

Case in point,

I have a folder structure which looks something like this:

```
project
    file_1.txt
    file_2.ext
    Dockerfile
    sub_dir_1
        file_1_1.py
        file_1_2.py
    sub_dir_2
        file_2_1.py
        file_2_2.py
```

But all these files when copied into the docker looks like this

```
project  
file_1.txt  
file_2.ext  
Dockerfile   
file_1_1.py  
file_1_2.py
file_2_1.py
file_2_2.py  
...  
many_other_files
```

For copying the files to the container, I've added this line in the Dockerfile

`COPY ./* /project/`

What do I do in order to maintain the folder structure in the docker container? Or is it normal for docker to do such a thing, in which case, what about the code of mine which uses relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ADD`

`ADD . /my-project/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) which will create a directory if it doesn't exists, then run [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) without specifying `*` (its not needed), just pass the current directory:

```
WORKDIR /project
COPY . /project
```

Comment: (`WORKDIR` will affect the destination of `COPY`, the second half; you can `COPY . ./` to take advantage of it.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for your comment, isn't this will work since we already giving the full path to destination?